# How to restore $args for get_avatar custom "class"?

Tags: avatar

I'm aware that you can pass a custom CSS class name in to an avatar using...

`<?php echo get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ); ?>`

Like...

`get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 128, null, null, array('class' => array('img-responsive', 'img-rounded') ) );`

But I am filtering `get_avatar` to replace Gravatar with a Media Library image, and the code seems to have rendered the `$args` portion unfunctional.

Here is my call with the `$args` class addition...

`echo get_avatar($curauth->ID, $size='150', $default='', $alt=$curauth->display_name, $args = array( 'class' => array( 'rounded-circle' ) ) );`

But that doesn't add anything.

Here is the filter code...

```
  /**
   * Use ACF image field as avatar
   * @author Mike Hemberger
   * @link http://thestizmedia.com/acf-pro-simple-local-avatars/
   * @uses ACF Pro image field (tested return value set as Array )
   */
  add_filter('get_avatar', 'tsm_acf_profile_avatar', 10, 5);
  function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {

       $user = null; // This added by Robert Andrews to overcome "Notice: Undefined variable" for $user

      // Get user by id or email (get_avatar needs to get a user by either id or email, so account for both)
      if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

          $id   = (int) $id_or_email;
          $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );

      } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

          if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
              $id   = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
              $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
          }

      } else {
          $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
      }

      if ( ! $user ) {
          return $avatar;
      }

      // Get the user id
      $user_id = $user->ID;

      // Get the file id
      $image_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'avatar', true); // CHANGE TO YOUR FIELD NAME

      // Bail if we don't have a local avatar
      if ( ! $image_id ) {
          return $avatar;
      }

      // Get the file size
      $image_url  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); // Set image size by name
      // Get the file url
      $avatar_url = $image_url[0];
      // Get the img markup
      /* Run through Cloudinary
         cf. http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#modify_image_shape_and_style
         crop fill, gravity face, enhance sharpen, 300 wide and tall only to get square image */
      $avatar = '<img alt="' . $alt . '" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/w_300,h_300,c_fill,g_face,e_sharpen,b_rgb:ccc/' . $avatar_url . '" class="img-fluid avatar avatar-' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" width="' . $size . '"/>';

      // Return our new avatar
      return $avatar;
  }
```

I have tried added `$args` to the function declaration, like so...

`function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ) {`

... but then the blog page returns: `Warning: Missing argument 6 for tsm_acf_profile_avatar() in /home/path/wp-content/plugins/plugin/my-gravatar-replacement-plugin.php on line 26`

Someone suggested looking at pluggable.php and copying some relevant code from the `get_avatar` part there, but I don't understand.

How do I restore `$args` functionality so I can continue adding custom classes to my avatars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar/) for teh `get_avatar()` filter, you'll see that callbacks can accept 6 arguments:

> `apply_filters( 'get_avatar', string $avatar, mixed $id_or_email, int $size, string $default, string $alt, array $args )`

Which means that your callback function is accepting the arguments correctly, including the 6th argument, `$args`:

```
function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
```

The problem is that `$args` isn't being passed into your callback function. This is because `add_filter()` only passes the number of arguments specified in the last argument, `$accepted_args`. See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/):

> **$accepted_args**
>
> (int) (Optional)
>
> The number of arguments the function accepts. Default value: 1

This is basically a long-winded way of saying that you need to change `5` to `6` in your `add_filter()` call:

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'tsm_acf_profile_avatar', 10, 6);
```

Comment: Ah. So if I modify these like:

      `add_filter('get_avatar', 'tsm_acf_profile_avatar', 10, 6);`
      `function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ) {`

and `get_avatar` passes:

`$args = array( 'class' => array( 'rounded-circle' ) ) ;`

… that should work, is that right?

Seeing nothing, but must echo class out here?:

`$avatar = '<img alt="' . $alt . '" src="$avatar_url . '" class="img-fluid avatar avatar-' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" width="' . $size . '"/>';`

… I see where, but I don’t know how to access the “class” arg.

Comment: You need to get the class from `$args['class']`, but you should check it exists first (`isset( $args['class'])`)

Comment: How to overcome warning `Notice: Array to string conversion ... ` when I write `$args['class']` in to the `img` mark-up?

Comment: `$args['class']` can be an array or a string, you need to account for both. Simplest solution is just to cast as an array then implode it: `$class = (array) $args['class']; echo implode( ' ', $class );`

Comment: You should look at [the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) of `get_avatar()` to see how it handles all the arguments.

Comment: Solution summary: 1) Pass class name in get_avatar $args array as normal, 2) Add $args to function, 3) increase accepted args from 5 to 6 (args is sixth), 4) Cast as array, 5) Implode class names in img mark-up.